# How does it work, that when I always open the app, it run the method and not only when I click on run?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, methods

I want a random number every time I open the app and not only when I press "Run". How do I do that?
If I close the App on the Emulator/on my Samsung and opened the App again, always the same quote is here.
When I cklick the (re)run button in Android Studio only then it runs the Methode `setQuote()` again.

What can I do, that this method always run when i open my app?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override`enter code here`
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setQuote();
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void setQuote(){

    List<String> listQuotes= new ArrayList<>();
    listQuotes.add("Quote 1");
    listQuotes.add("Quote 2");
    listQuotes.add("Quote 3");
    listQuotes.add("Quote 4");

    int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, listQuotes.size()+ 1);
    
    String quote = listQuotes.get(random);
     
  
    TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    textview.setText(quote);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

}
```

Comment: aside note: `listQuotes.size()+ 1` can raise `ArrayOutOfBundsException`, just keep it `listQuotes.size()`

Comment: Actually, your exact code is working for me and it is randomizing the text each time I reopen the app. P.S. Like Zain said, the +1 after the size throws an ```IndexOutOfBoundsException```.

Comment: "If I close the App on the Emulator/on my Samsung and opened the App again, always the same quote is here".   I'm assuming your're not closing the app really ( not clicking back ), but clicking HOME ( the "O" on the  old navigation bar or swipe-up in gestures).
This will casue the Activity to "pause"  and "stop", but wont get destroyed, so onCreate wont get invoked.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you look into [the Android Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

onCreate() gets called the first time the Activity gets started, if you go away and reopen the app onCreate() might not get called again. Instead look at methods like onStart or onResume. onResume() gets called each time the Activity is visible.

So just try moving setQuote() from onCreate to onStart or onResume (which you override, same as onCreate)

Comment: Okay, I'll take a closer look at the Android Lifecycle. I am just a beginner... 

But onStart() or onResume() does not work either.

Comment: It should work, you can verify that they get called with Log.d  

Btw why do you have requiresApi? There is nothing I can see that requires that at the top of your methods